# where are the names of angels in evangelion written

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, rebuild-of-evangelion

I have seen people online write the names of angles in evangelion like Samsel, Arael etc. etc. but I have watched the anime many types, but I have never seen their names visually appearing in the anime. also are the names may be written on the Japanese black text screens that appear before angel appearing please help.

Comment: "*are the names may be written on the Japanese black text screens that appear before angel*" yes, you're correct.